# ASP.NET Core Boolean property binding on form POST does not work as expected

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I have got a bare-bones ASP.NET Core MVC application generated off of the MVC project template. The `HomeController` has been modified to expose two `Index` method overloads – one for GET and one for POST request, both of which render the same `Index.cshtml` view with a simple `BooleanInputsViewModel`:

```
public class BooleanInputsViewModel
{
  public bool IsImportant { get; set; }
  public bool IsActive { get; set; }
  public List<string> Messages { get; } = new List<string>();
}
```

The `Index.cshtml` view looks like this:

```
@model AspNetCoreBooleanInputs.Models.BooleanInputsViewModel

<h2>
  @nameof(this.Model.IsImportant) = @this.Model.IsImportant.ToString()
  <br />
  @nameof(this.Model.IsActive) = @this.Model.IsActive.ToString()
</h2>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input asp-for="IsImportant" />
    <label asp-for="IsImportant">
    </label>

    <input asp-for="IsActive" />
    <label asp-for="IsActive">
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul>
      @foreach(string message in this.Model.Messages)
      {
        <li>@message</li>
      }
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Finally, the `HomeController` `Index` methods are implemented like this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
  var model = new BooleanInputsViewModel();
  model.Messages.Add($"GET values: {nameof(model.IsImportant)} = {model.IsImportant}, {nameof(model.IsActive)} = {model.IsActive}");
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(BooleanInputsViewModel model)
{
  model.Messages.Add($"POST values: {nameof(model.IsImportant)} = {model.IsImportant}, {nameof(model.IsActive)} = {model.IsActive}");

  model.IsActive = !model.IsActive;
  model.IsImportant = !model.IsImportant;

  model.Messages.Add($"Negated POST values: {nameof(model.IsImportant)} = {model.IsImportant}, {nameof(model.IsActive)} = {model.IsActive}");
  return this.View(model);
}
```

The POST handler negates the two model properties and passes the modified model back to the view. However, the negated values are not reflected in the rendered form as it always renders the originally POST-ed values. To me this looks like a bug. Do I miss something obvious?

The complete ASP.NET Core project is posted here - https://github.com/PaloMraz/AspNetCoreBooleanInputs.

**Edit based on @Chris Platt's answer below:**

Hi Chris, thank you for the prompt answer. I have verified that using the `ModelState` dictionary as you suggested works as expected, e.g.:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(BooleanInputsViewModel model)
{
  model.Messages.Add($"POST values: {nameof(model.IsImportant)} = {model.IsImportant}, {nameof(model.IsActive)} = {model.IsActive}");

  // This does NOT work:
  //model.IsActive = !model.IsActive;
  //model.IsImportant = !model.IsImportant;

  // This works:
  this.ModelState[nameof(model.IsActive)].RawValue = !model.IsActive;
  this.ModelState[nameof(model.IsImportant)].RawValue = !model.IsImportant;

  model.Messages.Add($"Negated POST values: {nameof(model.IsImportant)} = {model.IsImportant}, {nameof(model.IsActive)} = {model.IsActive}");
  return this.View(model);
}
```

However, I still find it a very cumbersome behavior, because the model has already been bound once the `Index` method gets called. Why is the binding occurring again in the call to the `View` method, effectively ignoring the passed in `model` instance? This does not look right to me, sorry.

Besides, can you tell me please where did you get the information about the `ModelState` dictionary composition? The official documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding does not mention `ViewData/ViewBag` as sources; only form values, route values and query string...

Answer (score 0):

The values your form fields are set to come from `ModelState`, which is composed of values from `Request`, `ViewData/ViewBag`, and *finally* `Model`. Importantly, `Model` is a last resort, so once you've done a post, the posted value (in `Request`) will be what the field is set to, regardless of any changes you make to `Model`.

I haven't tried doing this in ASP.NET Core, but you *should* be able to set `ModelState["IsActive"].RawValue` and `ModelState["IsImportant"].RawValue` instead. Assuming you can change the value in `ModelState`, then it will display as you want on your view.